# How can I delete all text after the 3rd point in notepa++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text like this:

```
kss005  81.7.11.92
kss005  81.7.18.11
kss005  81.7.17.19
kss005  81.7.15.150
kss005  81.7.16.97
kss020  103.161.132.60
```

and i want it to look like this

```
kss005  81.7.11
kss005  81.7.18
kss005  81.7.17
kss005  81.7.15
kss005  81.7.16
kss020  103.161.132
```

Comment: Regex replace with `( \d+[.]\d+[.]\d+)[.]\d+` to `( \1)`?

Comment: can you please specify

Comment: Use the replace feature. Select "regular expression". Use those two expressions as "find what" and "replace with". Click "replace all".

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.\d+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.      # a dot
\d+     # 1 or more digits
$       # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]